# What order are compiler flags executed in and which of these actually 'make it through'?

Tags: r, makefile, fortran, gfortran

I am compiling an `R` package and using the following `Makevars`:

```
PKG_LIBS += $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
PKG_FCFLAGS += -O3 -ffree-line-length-none -fimplicit-none -mtune=native -ffast-math
```

However, when I install the package, I get the following:

```
gfortran -O3 -ffree-line-length-none -fimplicit-none -mtune=native -ffast-math -fpic -g -O2
```

I know that there are some flags which `R` might want to keep due to safety, but I am just wondering which of these flags are actually being used. Is `-O2` over-riding `-O3`? Is `-ffast-math` being used at all?

Comment: Normally the latter overrides the first one. ffast-math should remain in effect.